# Assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' version 10 or higher could not be found

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework, azure

I Have a problem. I'm not able to add a Migration to my ASP.NET WebAPI 2 Project. I get error:

> "Spatial types and functions are not available for this provider
>   because the assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' version 10 or higher
>   could not be found."

I know there are several questions and answers about this, like:

- ['Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' version 10 or higher could not be found on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174197/microsoft-sqlserver-types-version-10-or-higher-could-not-be-found-on-azure)
- ["Spatial types and functions are not available" error when converting a string to DbGeometry in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104536/spatial-types-and-functions-are-not-available-error-when-converting-a-string-t)

But! The problem is...

- I already have installed Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.
- I already have Global.asax configured with: **SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~/bin"))** into the Application_Start.
- Reference is set to local copy > true.
- NuGet packages are all updated.
- I already try to downgrade and upgrade the package.

This is the full error when I try to run for example **Add-Migration v002**:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Spatial types and functions are not
>   available for this provider because the assembly
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' version 10 or higher could not be found.
>   en
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlTypesAssemblyLoader.GetSqlTypesAssembly()
>   en
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlSpatialServices.GeographyFromText(String
>   wellKnownText)    en
>   System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography.FromText(String wellKnownText) 
>   en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.ColumnModel.CreateDefaultValue()
>   en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.ColumnModel..ctor(PrimitiveTypeKind
>   type, TypeUsage typeUsage)    en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.BuildColumnModel(EdmProperty
>   property, TypeUsage conceptualTypeUsage, TypeUsage
>   defaultStoreTypeUsage, IDictionary`2 annotations)    en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.BuildColumnModel(EdmProperty
>   property, ModelMetadata modelMetadata, IDictionary`2 annotations)
>   en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.<>c__DisplayClass2e3.b__2df(EdmProperty
>   p)    en
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.IEnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1
>   ts, Action`1 action)    en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.BuildCreateTableOperation(EntitySet
>   entitySet, ModelMetadata modelMetadata)    en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.b__194(EntitySet
>   es)    en
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>
>   en System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>
>   en System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(ModelMetadata
>   source, ModelMetadata target, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator,
>   MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String
>   sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)    en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument
>   sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Lazy`1
>   modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator
>   migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String
>   targetModelVersion)    en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Scaffold(String
>   migrationName, String namespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)    en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder.Scaffold(String
>   migrationName, Boolean ignoreChanges)    en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Scaffold(MigrationScaffolder
>   scaffolder)    en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
>   en System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate
>   callBackDelegate)    en
>   System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   en System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
>   runner)    en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Scaffold(String
>   migrationName, String language, String rootNamespace, Boolean
>   ignoreChanges)    en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name,
>   Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)    en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   en
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' version 10 or higher could not be found on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174197/microsoft-sqlserver-types-version-10-or-higher-could-not-be-found-on-azure)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

After a lot of research I just installed "Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2012" from:

- **X86** - http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239643&clcid=0x409
- **X64** - http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239644&clcid=0x409

Worked like a charm!

Comment: This worked on a new machine in which a project that uses EDMX ( which i hate,  if i'm going to use EF, i'm going with code first )      ....  It was blowing up and my previous machine for 2 weeks ago had same version of visual studio ,  2015 etc..    So other than me installing sql server 2016 for the first time on this new machine... that is the only thing that is different so I'm glad I found your answer,   to me since me and several others on same project never had this problem ... it is very frustrating to see this.   Thx

Comment: Omg, thank you. I have been wrestling with this forever and all the other stuff I found about downloading the nuget for sql types didn't work, I think because my entities are in a separate project/assembly. So, when I tried to do any migration stuff it failed. After installing the CLR MSI everything worked fine.

Comment: Which machine did you install these on? (WWW server? DB server? Your local development PC?)

Answer (score 17):

Make sure you are not missing a binding redirect

```
  <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

Add this to the web.config > system.webServer >> runtime >> assemblyBinding node

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Thanks...I installed Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, but that alone didn't work. I added that line and it fixed the error.

Answer (score 2):

the problem may be "virtual". You need to have SqlServerSpatial140.dll in bin folder at the moment you issue add-migration command. 
Just copy the .dll to bin for development purpose and replace manually the version (x86/x64) during deployment.
Sql Server (2012+) already has the assembly installed.

Comment: The dll has been always there. That's not the problem. The issue has been resolved with the accepted green answer.

Comment: The problem arises when you use MVC Code First. This is not THE solution, just a workaround.

Comment: The Green Answer installs the .dll to a Sql Server. In 2016+ it is already installed. The problem arises in Code First development only.
I don't pretend for a Final Solution, just share my own experience.

Comment: I have 2016+ already insalled and I had to install the CLR Types anyway

Comment: Additional installation wouldn't hurt.
Thank you for sharing your experience. I'm still in the process.