# Azure function and Spatial types and the assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types'

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-functions

Got an Azure Function that is supposed to call the context to update the values of DbGeography. I keep getting this exception:

> Spatial types and functions are not available for this provider because the assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' version 10 or higher could not be found.

I installed the NuGet package in the Azure Function project. Currently, the Azure Function is not published, I run it locally. It would be nice to solve these issues, even when the function is deployed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your error message, I suppose your issue is about when you try to deploy to a machine that does not have the CLR Types for SQL Server installed.

You said you have installed the Nuget package, so I suggest you could also check whether the appropriate version of the native **SqlServerSpatial110.dll** assembly is copied to the output directory and deployed with your application. For more details about this issue, you could refer to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adonet/2013/12/09/microsoft-sqlserver-types-nuget-package-spatial-on-azure/).

You could also check whether you have installed the Microsoft System CLR Types. Fore more details ,you could read this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221467/assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-types-version-10-or-higher-could-not-be-found).

> After a lot of research I just installed "Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2012" from:
>
> X86 - http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239643&clcid=0x409
>
> X64 - http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239644&clcid=0x409
>
> Worked like a charm!

Besides, If I use SqlGeography in Microsoft.SqlServer.Types package, it works fine on my side:

The code in Azure function:

[image]

The result in Azure portal:

[image]